# masked kernel in convolution in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's say:

```
x = torch.arange(16, dtype=torch.float).reshape(1, 1, 4, 4)
```

and a 2d convolution layer is:

```
layer = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
layer.weight.data[:] = 1.
layer.bias.data[:] = 0.
```

Normally, passing *x* to *layer* will give:

```
>>layer(x)    
tensor([[[[10., 18.],
              [42., 50.]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>)
```

Considering having 4 mask filters, how it is done to mask kernel in each step?
for example the following picture indicates 4 filters(white: True, black: False)
[image: stride=2 and kernel_size=2 for given x]

The output should be:

```
tensor([[[[5., 15.],
          [30., 40.]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>)
```

**P.S:** all masks are obtained by missing pixels in 2d input array. So 4 masks above are actually a matrix with the same shape as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Element-wise multiplication between input and the mask before feeding it to a Conv2d method would be enough.(masking input is much easier than masking kernel itself !!):

```
mask = torch.tensor([[[1, 1, 1, 0]], [[1, 0, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 0, 1]], [[0, 1, 1, 1]]], dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=False).reshape(1, 1, 4, 4)

>>layer(torch.mul(x, mask))
tensor([[[[5., 15.],
          [30., 40.]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>)
```

**P.S** Thanks to @Shai I got the idea from partial convolution represented in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07723). However it does some extra manipulation on output. it defines a mask ratio and I guess does some weighting the final output based on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [partial convolution](https://github.com/NVIDIA/partialconv) from Nvidia research.

A more detailed description is given in their ECCV 2018 paper [*Image Inpainting for Irregular Holes Using Partial Convolutions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07723)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this paper seems relevant. I need to check it out whether there is a solution for my problem or not.